# How to find the velocity and accelaration in a 3d space with 6 degrees of freedom?

Tags: linear-algebra, coordinate-systems

I have the following rigid body:

[image: support platform degrees of freedom[]ref:Dynamics modeling and loads analysis of an offshore floating wind turbine]

I assume that the body is a symmetric cylinder.*x,y,z* are the axes of the reference frame resulting from a transformation involving three orthogonal rotations *θ1,θ2,θ3* about the axes of an orignal reference frame *X,Y,Z*.With first order small angle approximations and neglecting the terms of higher order in the Taylor expansion,the Euler-angle transformation the original and transformed reference frame is:

[image]

Until here everything is understantable.My question is how to find the velocities and accelerations in the transformed reference frame?

Answer (score 0):

Differentiating both sides with respepct to time, you get $\begin{bmatrix} v_x \\ v_y \\ v_z \end{bmatrix} = A \begin{bmatrix} v_X \\ v_Y \\ v_Z \end{bmatrix}$ where $A$ is the matrix containing the thetas. Similarly, taking second derivatives with respect to time on both sides gets you the accelerations.

Comment: Maybe I wasn't clear in my question,but i belive your answer is not correct.$\theta_{1},\theta_{2},\theta_{3}$ are the rotation of the body which are not constant.So i believe its more complicated than just differentiating to x,y,z with respect to time.